# Is temperature-induced change in the volume of balloons dependent on gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

Which balloon will have higher relative change in volume, helium balloon immersed in liquid nitrogen or air balloon immersed in liquid nitrogen? Since volume is directly proportional to temperature does the gas in the balloon matter?

Comment: The ideal gas law says it doesn't matter.  Your question is basically asking about how accurate the ideal gas law is for real gases at extreme temperatures.

Comment: In reply to the comment you deleted: The ideal gas law says they will shrink the same.  In reality they wont.  You're basically asking when and how and by how much does the ideal gas law break down.  It's a very hard question in the general case.  My guess though is that helium will shrink more because it's a homogeneous gas and a smaller atom than the other gases.

Comment: @Brandon Enright: The ideal gas law is not applicable for air at liquid nitrogen temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

While studying the behavior of a gas filled balloon on cooling down, one needs to understand how the gases behave while being cooled. A helium filled balloon immersed in liquid nitrogen would just undergo shrinkage due to contraction of helium gas. On the other hand, a balloon filled with air will behave differently. Air roughly contains 77% nitrogen, 22% oxygen and 1% argon, carbon dioxide, etc. Any stable balloon in atmospheric air must have at least 1 atmosphere inside it, otherwise it will shrink (In reality the pressure inside is actually more than outside so as to overcome the elastic force of the balloon material). If this air filled balloon is immersed in liquid nitrogen, the nitrogen part of air inside will reduce in volume while the oxygen part will simply turn to liquid (argon will shrink, CO2 will turn solid!). The volume loss due to phase change is much more than simple contraction of gas on cooling. As a result, the air balloon will actually reduce much more in size as compared to the helium filled balloon.